# Unable to pass props to child Component from Parent Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my parent component Search.js

```
class Search extends Component {
state = {
    hcps: [],
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchingData();
}

fetchingData = () => {
    axios.get('/hcp-overview-panel')
    .then(res => {
        const hcps = res.data;
        console.log('data from fetch: ', hcps)
        this.setState({hcps: hcps},()=>{console.log('state after state: ',this.state)})
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(`Error: $(error)`));
}

render() {
    console.log('State: ',this.state);
    return(
         <div>
           <Name hcps={this.state.hcps} />
         </div>
         )}
```

And this is my child component Name.js.

```
class Name extends Component {

state = {
    hcpFromSearch: this.props.hcps,
    data: [28, 48, 40, 19],
    labels: ["In Person Call", "RTE", "MobilePush", "Speaker Program"],
};
 render() {
   console.log('from search:', this.props.hcps)
   return (
<div>
 <div>
    <h2 class="no-margins">
       {this.state.hcpFromSearch.hcp_overview.name}
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
   )}
```

This is the json.

```
   "hcp_overview" : {
            "name" : "Martin Alan Menter, MD, FAAD",
            "designation": "snlam",
            "specialty": "sksn",
            "top_affiliation": "snksn",
            }
```

I'm getting this error in running this code: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.
Basically, when I console.log, I'm getting an empty state and for some reason the axios request isn't getting done. Mind you, when I don't pass the Name component (that is just comment out that call to the Name component), I can fetch the data easily.
I'm stuck on this for quite some time.

[image]

And this is the JSON when I comment out the Name component.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just made a minor change in what Konstantin told me. I called the child component using this instead:

```
 <div>
    {this.state.hcps.length !==0 && <Name hcps={this.state.hcps}/>}
 </div>
```

It does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is not a best practice to initialize state of child using passed props. You can simply use props. Second, api call is an asynchronous process. Props are passed immediately, they are not waiting for your call to be completed. Thus, you should apply conditional rendering, something like that would suffice:

```
<div>
  {this.state.hcps.length !==0 && <Name hcps={this.state.hcps}/>}
</div>
```

Comment: So I tried what you said, but now even though I don't get the error, the Name component is not getting showed up on the screen. I can only see the Search component on the screen.

Comment: Did you see a state update of Search component? Is `this.state.hcps.hcp_overview` a correct property? If not it always gives undefined. You should have some property , which exists.

Comment: Yes, I can see that the JSON is passed to the state and that it is updated. I can see the HCP name as part of it but for some reason now, the Name component is just not getting shown. I also tried passing it directly as props instead of setting state of child using passed props like you mentioned.

Comment: Ok, I found the solution. I used this code instead: {this.state.hcps.length !==0 && <Name hcps={this.state.hcps}/>}  . Thanks for telling me the thought process :) Modify your answer so that I can upvote and accept it.